# Join tables in Grails

Tags: grails

I got two classes

```
class A {
    String name
    static hasMany[b:B]
    static mapping={
        b joinTable:[name:'A_B', column: 'b_id', key: 'a_id']
    }
}

class B {
    String name
}
```

Now I should join the table class B and A_B table where A_B store both
the table id's. I wrote the query

```
select b.name from B b,A_B ab where b.id=ab.b_id
```

but it throws an error that A_B is not mapped

Comment: if A_B store A and B's ids then it should be many-to-many relation.

Comment: joinTable is used as such you are telling on which `column` the tables to be joined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create a many to many relationship

```
class A {
    String name

    static hasMany = [b:B]

    static mapping={
        b joinTable:[name:'A_B']
    }
}

class B {
    String name

    static belongsTo = A    
    static hasMany = [b:B]

    static mapping={
        b joinTable:[name:'A_B']
    }
}
```